# Use cv2.imshow() to display an np.array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

so at the moment im accesing the BGR Channels of images and do a bit of calculation around them.

Like the mean or standard deviation.. stuff like that.

As far as i know i dont have to convert numPy Arrays to display them with cv2.imshow().

But when I display my array with this command:

```
#with the help of the PIL Libary
data = Image.fromarray(image_array)
data.save('SavedArrayAsPic.png')
```

My Output is correct. Its an Image with another color.

But when I write:

```
cv2.imshow("my Array as a Pic", image_array)
```

It shows the wrong image with an old color pattern.

I want to use cv2.imshow to display videos in RealTime. With the PIL Libary i just save the images.

So what could be the difference?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opencv has BGR channel ordering, PIL and matplotlib use RGB order

try not to mix different libraries with different paradigms